# Creating a dictionary/map in Coq

Tags: dictionary, coq, formal-verification

I want to be able to have a map from any type to any type in Coq. So far I have had some success `using Coq.FSets.FMapList` from the standard library, but I have only been able to create maps where the key is a natural number, by doing the following.

```
Require Import Coq.FSets.FMapList.
Require Import Coq.Structures.OrderedTypeEx.

Module Import NatMap := FMapList.Make(Nat_as_OT).

(* whatever I want to do with my NatMap *)
```

I know that `NatMap := FMapList.Make(Nat_as_OT).` is declaring that I want to use a map whose keys are `Nat_as_OT`. However, `FMapList.Make` will only accept an `OrderedType` as an argument. Its there a way I can make my own `OrderedType`? Or is there a better way of creating a map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't easily find maps from any type to any type, because for such a map to work you at least need to be able to distinguish two element of the type used for keys.  If you only have this capability (testing whether two elements are the same), then maps can be implemented in a fairly inefficient way: you basically handle a list of pairs `(key, value)` and the cost of retrieving the value associated to a key is proportional to the number of keys that are already handled in your map, on average.

If you want to be slightly more efficient, a usual trick is to have hash keys, but you need to be able to compute hash values, so your type cannot be completely arbitrary.

In the end, there is the possibility to use maps based on a type that has an order.  In this case, it is quite easy to implement the map is such a way that retrieving the value for a key with a cost that is logarithmic in the number of keys, on average.

Now, how do you create an `OrderedType` object?  You need to instantiate module type `MiniOrderedType`.  So, for your type you need to say what function will play the role of `eq`, `lt`, and show the various important properties listed in the `MiniOrderedType` module type (see [this file](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Structures.OrderedType.html)).  There are several example of this construction in [this example file](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Structures.OrderedTypeEx.html)).

Answer (score 2):

> a map from any type to any type in Coq

To refine Yves's answer, the only thing that is a map from any type `A` to any type `B` in Coq is the function space `A -> B` (or `A -> option B`)

That being said, this is not such a bad type for maps, once you add functional extensionality, but of course it lacks some basic operations that could be added with a bit of effort.

Comment: Why not suggest an edit to Yves's answer rather than adding a partial answer?

Comment: Umm, interesting point, I am not sure about it, I guess I'll leave it to Yves' criteria.

Comment: @ejgallego is there a specific reason why you can't create a map that can use anything as keys like std::map in C++ does? Or is it just that it hasn't been implemented in the standard library? Also, what do you mean by "functional extensionality"?

Comment: ahh. I just remembered. C++ requires the keys to have an ordering...which is the exact same requirement that `FMapList` is giving. I guess I've figured out that part. I'm still not sure what you mean by "functional extensionality" though.

Comment: @setholopolus indeed there is a specific reason. In Coq, a type `T` can be a much more complicated structure than a type in C++. for example, the statement of Fermat's last theorem is a type in Coq. So as Yves has hinted, you want to restrict the domain of your maps to types that can be at least compared. Note that `std::map` cannot create maps over arbitrary objects, as your class needs to provide the `<` operator.

Comment: You can search this site for a complete explanation of functional extensionality, but in a nutshell, it is the principle that says that two functions `f,g : A -> B` are equal iff their outputs are equal for all the arguments `forall x : A, f x = g x`.

Comment: I tried to edit my answer following ejgallego's idea, but I am reluctant giving too much importance to `A -> option B` because this solution indicates how a map can be viewed when reasoning, but not how to implement it.  In other words, plain function types and extensionality are interesting tools for reasoning, but they don't bring implementation solutions.

Comment: I fully agree, we tend to use "computable" vs "noncomputable" map too easily. In fact this kind of question comes often about maps and sets, I wonder if we could add it to the wiki?